# how to debug legacy javascript code (works fine with IE, but abnormal in Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Generally the problem is "what is the suggested routine to debug a legacy javascript code when the code works fine in IE but abnormal in Google Chrome"?

I have a legacy program. I met the following issue:

1. A JSP page calls the backend java servlet, the servlet returns a html table.
2. This HTML table has already been sorted by servlet.
3. This HTML table is affected by local JS and CSS to make it more beautiful.
4. Everything runs fine in IE8, Safari and Firefox.
5. But the table appears abnormal in Google Chrome. The result are no longer sorted here.

The above situation are not a javascript grammar error. So how & where can I start to solve it?

Comment: may be some tags incorrect, try to validate it with any html validators.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should use `alert()`, `console.log()` or set it as the innerHTML of `<div id="log"></div>` in order to get the html table returned by the servlet.
Then, each time an instruction of your js modifies its code, do it again.

This way you will find which instruction of your code doesn't work as you expect on Chrome, find out why and how can it work.

Then, use conditionals to execute different instructions depending on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

By using developer tools in Google Chrome. Add breakpoint before action and add variables that are involved to `watch expression` panel. Debug line by line and watch variables change - you will be able to see where everything goes wrong. Here's how: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints